# Contributions of Descartes

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, descartes, rationalism

What ideas did Descartes have about knowledge and reality that were so incongruent with the prevailing neo-Aristotelian paradigm of knowing the real essences of things through abstracting from sense perceptions?

Comment: Generic information of this sort is available in online encyclopedias, e.g. [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#MetTurComPhyDis). This site takes more pointed questions.

Comment: See [Descartes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/): "he offered a new vision of the natural world: a world of matter possessing a few fundamental properties and interacting according to a few universal laws. This natural world included an immaterial mind that, in human beings, was directly related to the brain. In metaphysics, he provided arguments for the existence of God, to show that the essence of matter is extension, and that the essence of mind is thought."